# Container won't center

Tags: html, css

This container stubbornly refuses to center. Demo: http://codepen.io/Diego7/pen/KzXgZN

I've tried just about every centering code I can find on the web, to no avail.

Removing `width: 90%;` from the css aligns the container to the left, even though `margin: 0 auto;` is telling it to center.

Sorry if this question isn't up to StackOverflow's 'standards', but codingforums.com are down at the moment :(

Thanks heaps!

HTML

```
<div class="container">  

<article>
    <header>
<img src="https://softwarereviews.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/bg-header-no-logo.png" width="972px"><br />  
        <h2>Information</h2>    
    </header>


  <p>There's currently is no information available. Sorry.</p>

    <footer>
&copy; 2016

    </footer>
</article>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
    @@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
}

.container {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:90%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: container-box;
}

article header h2 {
  color: #282828;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  display:inline;
  line-height: 1.3;

}
article p {
  font-size: 1em;
  display:inline;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #282828;
  max-width: 972px;
}
article footer {
  font-size: .9em;
  display:inline;
  color: #999;
}

a {
  color: #2790ae;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #0f6780;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.container` **is already centered**: if you change `background` to *red* you will see it. And, if you add `text-align` property its content will be centered too.

```
.container {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:90%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: container-box;

  text-align:center;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! You were right, it was centered, I just couldn't see it.

I had to make the 'width' the same as the width of the image, 972px, then 'text-align' to the left. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you make the width a bit narrower (like 70%), you see that it IS centered.

by the way: " list-style:none;" has no effect whatsoever, and "box-sizing: container-box;" should be "box-sizing: content-box;"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're centering the <div class="container">, but it doesn't look like it, because you're looking at the image.

If you want the image to take up the entire <div> element (so that any centering takes effect on both), try something like the following, instead of using an <img> element:

```
div.container {
    background-image: url(https://softwarereviews.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/bg-header-no-logo.png);
}
```

There are other properties you can use to fiddle with precisely how the image is displayed.  You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using container after float tag. It can create problem sometimes. So to avoiding this user <div class="clear"></div>. Also clear class properties would be:

.clear{
clear:both;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
height:0px;
font-size:0px;
line-height:0px;
float:none;
}

Hope it will be helpful..
```